# React/NextJS state issues

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a simple script in NextJS/React and I am struggling to save state and reuse data in a variable.

```
import React from 'react';
import Head from 'next/head'
import Image from 'next/image'
import axios from 'axios';
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'

export default function Home() {

const [ETHdata, setETHData] = React.useState({ });

const [CryptoDATA, setCryptoDATA] = React.useState({ });
```

all good here :)

Now I am fetching data from an API:

```
  const fetchETH = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=Ethereum&vs_currencies=CHF&include_24hr_change=true'); 
    
    if (res.data && res.data.ethereum) {
      setETHData(res.data.ethereum);
    }

  }
```

but since it can be tiring to re-write the same thing for say 10 cryptocurrencies I fetch them all at once here:

```
const fetchCryptoDATA= async () => {
  const res = await axios.get('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=bitcoin%2Cethereum%2Ccrypto-com-chain%2Csolana%2Cavalanche-2%2Cblockstack%2Cflow%2Clitecoin%2Calgorand%2Ccardano&vs_currencies=CHF&include_24hr_change=true'); 



if (res.data ) {
    setCryptoDATA(res.data);
}
console.log (CryptoDATA)

}
```

but when I display them:

```
 React.useEffect(() => {
    fetchETH();
    fetchCryptoDATA();
  }, []);
  return (
...
```

this works fine

```
<p>Ethereum {ETHdata['chf']}   {parseFloat(ETHdata['chf_24h_change']).toFixed(2)}</p>
```

but

```
<p>ETHEREUM {CryptoDATA['ethereum']['chf']}   {parseFloat(CryptoDATA['ethereum']['chf_24h_change']).toFixed(2)}</p>
```

will work the first time I load it but then return

"Cannot read property 'chf' of undefined "

I am sure it is something trivial and I kindly appreciate your help!

Comment: The error suggests that `CryptoDATA['ethereum']` is `undefined`.  When this occurs, what is the runtime value of `CryptoDATA`?

Comment: first time it loads has the api data, second time nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CryptoDATA['ethereum']` might be `undefined`.  Because the initial state of `CryptoDATA` is an empty object:

```
const [CryptoDATA, setCryptoDATA] = React.useState({ });
```

One option could be to set that initial state to the structure you expect:

```
const [CryptoDATA, setCryptoDATA] = React.useState({ ethereum: { } });
```

Another option could be to use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) when referencing properties of potentially-undefined objects:

```
CryptoDATA.ethereum?.chf
```

Or you might check if the property exists explicitly:

```
CryptoDATA['ethereum'] ? CryptoDATA['ethereum']['chf'] : null
```

You could even take a different approach entirely and track a boolean "loading" state during your AJAX operations and simply not render this part of the markup at all while the data is loading, replacing it instead with a spinner or loading indicator of some kind.

Any way that you approach it, the bottom line is still the same.  You can't reference a property on an `undefined` object.  And since the AJAX operation completes *after* the first render, initially the object you're looking for is currently `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

**Replace this line in your code.**

ETHEREUM {CryptoDATA['ethereum']?.['chf']}   {parseFloat(CryptoDATA['ethereum']?.['chf_24h_change'])?.toFixed(2)}